# MySQL parameter binding fails but inline succeeds

Tags: c++, mysql

I have a string of approximately 4.8MB (containing only BASE64-karakters, proven).

However, when I try to bind the string using this statement:

```
sqlPrepared_userdb_test->setString(1, Content); //Content is approximately 4.8MB
```

Mysql returns:

```
Incorrect string value: '\xF7/\x00\x00\xF0...' for column 'Content' at row 1 (error code: 1366, State: HY000)
```

However, when I include the content-string directly in the query (inline), the insert succeeds. The inline-query I use (skipped part of the content in the middle):

```
INSERT INTO Test (Content) Values('ajHEHAU......8837x=='); //Content is approximately 4.8MB
```

Why does binding fail, but inlining the exact same string succeeds?

***EDIT:***

```
Log("Inserting content!", false, "Debug");


for (auto& Char : Content) {
    if (Char >= 'a' && Char <= 'z') {
        }
    else if (Char >= 'A' && Char <= 'Z') {
        }
    else if (Char >= '0' && Char <= '9') {
        }
    else if (Char == '+') {
        }
    else if (Char == '/') {
        }
    else if (Char == '=') {
        }
    else {
        string Message = "Char in content: ";
        Message += Char;
        Message += " is not allowed!";
        Error(Message);
        // NO ERROR REPORTED HERE. CONTENT STRING SEEMS GOOD
        }
    }

try {
    sqlPrepared_userdb_test = mysqli_userdb->prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Test (Content) VALUES(?)");
    sqlPrepared_userdb_test->setString(1, Content);
    sqlPrepared_userdb_test->executeUpdate();
    }
catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
    Message = "Database test error: ";
    Message += e.what();
    Message += " (error code: ";
    Message += IntToString(e.getErrorCode());
    Message += ", State: ";
    Message += e.getSQLState();
    Message += ")";
    Log(Message, false, "Error");
    Error("Database");

    // CATCH TRIGGERS

    }

outfile.close();

sqlPrepared_userdb->setString(ParamOffset++, Content);
```

Comment: Please show us more code, apparently something is happening in `setString`, or before that.

Comment: @BartFriederichs, we have made a simple test. I have added the example to the original question

Comment: What is `Content`'s type?

Comment: The inline version looks a lot like base64 encoding and the string in the error message looks suspiciously not base64 encoded. I guess Content is not getting encoded when converted to a string.

Comment: @BartFriederichs, good question. I assume you mean the MySQL datatype of the column `Content`? This is `LONGTEXT`

Comment: @TimSeguine, as mentioned in the question I have compared the strings and they are both base64 valid. However, the setString has probably some memory issue

Comment: @ThomasvanHesteren no, I meant the C++ variable. I am thinking `setString` wants a `char *`, and gets a `string` ? (note I haven't used C++/MySQL using this library).

Comment: @BartFriederichs, the `Content` type in `C++` is a `string`, not a `char *`. The problem also occurs if I use `Content.c_str()` in the `setString` statement

Comment: Can you try to run it as `setString(Content.c_str())` ?

Comment: @BartFriederichs, see my comment. I have already tried that. Same result though

Comment: I just looked at the sourcecode of the connector library. It looks like for strings larger than 256k it treats the parameter as a blob. If I had to guess again, I'd bet the conversion from sql::SqlString to the blob type does base64decoding

Comment: @TimSeguine, that could be very well possible.. How can I then store LONGTEXT base64 encoded strings? Possibly good to know, we have also tried to store the first 1000 characters of the string, but also this failed.

Comment: I didn't dig deep enough to be sure, but my theory is easy enough to verify. If the theory is correct, then base64encoding it again before binding should succeed, but I don't think that is a great idea to put into production.  I don't know the library well enough to offer a real solution.